# Function definition of classmethod wrapper in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-method

Is there documentation on what the `@classmethod` decorator does?

```
>>> class Cls:
...     @classmethod
...     def cm(cls):
...         print ("cls")
... 
>>> Cls.cm()
cls
```

In other words, what is the actual function wrapper of `def classmethod(func)`?

Comment: yes it is a duplicate. suffice it to say that it is generally speaking a decision of style (shirt tucked in or untucked)... generally speaking, if you are modifying the CLASS itself and not instances of the class you'll want a classmethod. A method that might eb used by an INSTANCE of teh class but doesn't require referencing the instance itself might be a good reason to use a staticmethod.

Comment: For how it's defined, see the duplicate. For what it does, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)